# Making Emacs/Slime/Quicklisp/SBCL work in Windows

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime, quicklisp

I'm using the above combination in Windows 7.0 for several months now. Unfortunately a collegue advised me to install the slime-helper.el into emacs, with the result: Emacs Slime doesn't recognize QL any more.

I'm using SBCL 1.2.11 for Windows and from command-line this sbcl knows the ql installation.
This is my .sbclrc

```
;;; The following lines added by ql:add-to-init-file:
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames
                       "Documents/LISP/.asdf-install-dir/systems/setup.lisp"
                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))
```

I then typed

```
(ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")
```

and it compiled a lot. Finally it said

To use, add this to your ~/.emacs:

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/Documents/LISP/.asdf-install-dir/systems/slime-helper.el"))
;; Replace "sbcl" with the path to your implementation
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```

Now this is the corresponding part in my .emacs file

```
(load "c:/Users/xyz/Documents/LISP/.asdf-install-dir/systems/slime-helper.el")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "c:\\Progra~1\\Steelb~1\\12BDCB~1.11\\sbcl.exe")
```

I started up emacs and it came up just normally.

```
M-x slime
```

Still fine:

```
; SLIME 2015-06-01
CL-USER>
```

But then:

```
(ql:quickload :my-project)
```

returned

```
Package QL does not exist.
```

But the worst part is, if I remove slime-helper from .emacs-file, it again recognizes the quicklisp package but every call to ql locks up the emacs. I can wait for several minutes without getting any response.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Emacs Slime (REPL) doesn't know neither whether quicklisp is installed nor where it is installed. All you have to do to fix the problem is to **reinstall quicklisp at the Emacs' slime repl**. ("quicklisp.lisp" file should be in the SLIME REPL's current working folder.)

```
M-x slime 
CL-USER> (load "quicklisp.lisp")
CL-USER> (quicklisp-quickstart:install)
CL-USER> (ql:add-to-init-file)
```

Then, quicklisp will be reinstalled in the Emacs's HOME directory ("~/"). Now, you have installed the same quicklisp in the (a) Windows 10's HOME and (a) the Emacs' HOME. If you use quicklisp only at the Emacs' Slime REPL, the copy in the Windows 10' HOME is useless, and you can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who had this problem, I had a similar issue trying to use Windows + Emacs + Slime + SBCL + QL. In the end, it came down to a conflict between what Windows thought my home folder was and what Emacs (and hence, Slime) thought it was.

Windows: c:/users/username

Emacs: c:/users/username/appdata/roaming

When I installed quicklisp I invoked SBCL from a cmd prompt and so the process installed the quicklisp folder, and also the new .sbclrc, in c:/users/username.

Emacs Slime looks for these in c:/users/username/appdata/roaming.

I fixed this by just moving the quicklisp folder and .sbclrc in c:/users/username to c:/users/username/appdata/roaming, since I don't ever plan on interacting with SBCL except through Slime.